# Rewrite domain to uppercase

Tags: apache, ubuntu, nginx, next.js, nginx-reverse-proxy

Is it possible to rewrite the base URL/Domain to be in all uppercase?

Would like the user to see EXAMPLE.COM in their url bar if possible.

Ive tried several different rewrites and redirects without luck. I see most people want the exact opposite.

Server stack
ubuntu/apache2/nginx/nextjs app using cloudflare

Comment: If this is even possible, it will only work with some browsers. I notice that my browser always normalises the domain to lowercase.

Comment: And why would one want to do that? Shouting at one's customer rarely is a good idea ...